# how can I do a thing like the Gmail one when i click on an action bar button?

Tags: android, button, android-actionbar

I want something like the image on the right:

[image: gmail]

How can I do that?

Comment: Search for NavigationDrawer on Internet

Answer (score 0):

This is a Navigation Drawer You can find this here https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

Here you can find how to create this during creating new project https://stackoverflow.com/a/24120554/1770916